# Kivy Launcher: warning in logs file

Tags: kivy

My script runs without problems on W10, but same scrip falls down on Kivy Launcher. There are wanings in logs file. This warnings alert on script lines, where are used statics methods and globals variables. 
Warning example:

```
[WARNING           ] stderr:     height += Board.height_but * Board.count_but_line
[WARNING           ] stderr: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'height_but'
```

I tested the contents of variable and there is value into.

Cann you explain me it?

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Comment: I don't understand to information from link.